# How to prevent SSRF with Puppeteer?

Tags: javascript, node.js, puppeteer

Is SSRF an issue with puppeteer? From what I gather from this article it is (https://hackerone.com/reports/660565), but what are some prevention options if so?

Comment: This is rather broad. SO is a poor fit for questions that involve speculating on a large search space of possibiliities. Can you be a bit more specific and clarify a particular concern (code snippet or app/use case, for example)? From the linked report, if you use Puppeteer to generate PDFs, then make sure you're not following arbitrary hrefs.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.